# MPAndroidchartlibrary how can i adjust height of Bar Chart in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, mpandroidchart

I'm having trouble setting the size of the bar chart

[image]

I have the chart inside a fragment inside an Activity.

If i use setContentView(chart) it will fill the Whole screen, but i want to limit it.

here's the XML where the chart gets Placed:  (Changing the layout_height didn't help)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
    android:id="@+id/piechart"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp">
</com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart>
</ScrollView>
```

And heres the fragment:

```
package com.example.kim.s236322_mappe3.View;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.example.kim.s236322_mappe3.R;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class StatisticsFragment extends Fragment {
View view;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.statistics_layout,container,false);
    ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new BarEntry(4f, 0));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(8f, 1));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(6f, 2));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(12f, 3));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(18f, 4));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(9f, 5));

    BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");

    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    labels.add("January");
    labels.add("February");
    labels.add("March");
    labels.add("April");
    labels.add("May");
    labels.add("June");

    BarChart chart = new BarChart(getActivity().getBaseContext());
    BarChart layout = (BarChart) view.findViewById(R.id.piechart);
    layout.addView(chart);

    BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
    chart.setData(data);

    chart.setDescription("# of times Alice called Bob");
    dataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
    chart.animateY(5000);
    return view;
}

}
```

Comment: Why are you putting a Chart inside the chart? Just use the chart that you defined in the xml instead of creating a new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution here is very simple and not connected with `MPAndroidChart`.
Set `android:fillViewport="true"` to `ScrollView` so that is fill height and set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `BarChart`.